# Custom keyboard unavailable for normal user (Windows-10 1903)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, desktop-customization

I freshly installed Windows 10 x64 Pro (1903) on a laptop with erased SSD. Everything works fine, only the second user (myself as normal, local user) cannnot choose my custom keybord layout (only preinstalled keyboards can be chosen). The custom keyboard works well for the administrator account, but is not available to the normal user. Quite a mad situation, as before fresh installation it workes fine for all users (1809), but unfortunately the partition table crashed upon repeated unsuccessful update trials to 1903 !

Anybody has a good idea ? I suspect that I just have to add a registry key, but which one and where ? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Indeed my guess was correct: there were just **two** keys to be added manually in the registry (both values were taken from the administrator's values):

HK_CU\Keyboard layout\Preload\3                REG_SZ:  d0010807
HK_CU\Keyboard layout\Substitutes\d0010807     REG_SZ:  a0000807

Then it is necessary to reboot.

NB: no idea why "d0010807", but the second value comes from there:  HK_LM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts**a0000807**\layout file = *MyOwnKeyboard*.dll

Best also to be done for the .DEFAULT user !